# How do I replace tokens from one file with data from another?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, search, replace

I'm using Amazon Linux with bash shell.  I have a file with comma delimited data, where each row looks like this

```
2049,576804C7DF554416A9EA25B2A5A81514,X,
```

Then I have a second file, with comma delimited data, in which each row looks like this

```
id,user_name,user_email
```

Every row in the second file will be unique.  My question is, how do I take every row from the first file, and replace the second token with matching data (based on matching the second token from the first file with the first token from the second file) from the second file?  So for instance the lien I listed above would become

```
2049,576804C7DF554416A9EA25B2A5A81514,username1,email1,X,
```

Assuming that "576804C7DF554416A9EA25B2A5A81514" could be located in the second file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following script, using `gawk`

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk -F, 'tbl[$1]!=""{$2=tbl[$1];OFS=",";print;next}{tbl[$1]=$2;}' $1 $2
```

You pass in the two files with the token file first. This assumes the first file does not have any repetitions, and if the second file have any extra lines, where the first field does not have a match in the first file, then those lines are omitted from the output.

The `gawk` program builds up the associative array `tbl`, indexed by the first field, from the first file, then uses that to replace the second field for the second file, then prints the lines with replacements and using "," as field seperator. See `man gawk` for more details.

Comment: Thanks but should this print the output to the console?  I'm noticing if file1 contains "2041,id1,X,X,," and file2 contians "id1,username,email", running "gawk -F, 'tbl[$1]!=""{$2=tbl[$1];OFS=",";print;next}{tbl[$1]=$2;}' file1 file2" produces nothing.

Comment: I might have misunderstood how your input files look. Perhaps you can update the question with one example of each, and an example of the desired resulting output/file. I understood that the first field of file1 is to match with hte first field of file2, then the file2 line is printed but its second field is replaced by the corresponding second field from file1.